# Second Firefox install - with automatic updates if possible

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to get a second completely separate installation of Firefox working on Ubuntu 12.04?

I have one installation with many addons, and from time to time I notice that some sites don't work properly with these addons. I can startup Chrome, but sometimes I want to use Firefox without addons, without having to shutdown the normal installation to restart without addons, then restart with addons again, and then having to login to gmail, lastpass etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can solve your issue by **creating a new Firefox profile**. This new profile won't include the add-ons or history or bookmarks from your other firefox profile(s). So here is how to create a new profile:

1. Close all your Firefox windows.
2. Now open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

   `firefox -p`

   This would open the firefox profile manager.

---

[image]

---

3. From there select `Create Profile...` and you will see the following screens subsequently:

---

Select `Next` here

[image]

---

Here, type in a name for your new profile, select a folder where you want the files of this profile to be in and select `Finish`.

[image]

---

4. Now you would have successfully created a new firefox profile. You can select which profile to use by default by selecting the profile in the profile manager and ticking on `Use the selected profile without asking at startup`.

For more info please refer to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).